# How to disable default selection in tablayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

How could I disable default selection in tablayout? I tried,

```
android:focusedByDefault="false"
```

and

```
android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="false"
```

but both did not worked as expected. Please help me with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TabLayout is not designed to work like that. You could make custom horizontal RadioButtonGroup for such purposes. Just style your RadioButton with a selector to look and feel like a material tab.

EDIT: as TabLayout designed to be used w/ ViewPager, and ViewPager always have some View or Fragment visible in any momentum of time (except there is no adapter set to it or adapter's child count equal to 0), it's impossible to make w/ support library TabLayout.